# Monitor typing speed

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard

Is there any software that will sit in the background and monitor my typing speed (words per minute)?

OS: Windows 7 x64

Comment: Is there a "standard" that tells us what words are? Do you need an average over the last 15 minutes or since the beginning of the day or since the time you installed the software? Shall it be aware of suspend to RAM or suspend to disk and ignore those times?

Comment: I think since the beginning of the day would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [TypOmeter](http://www.informatics.no/progvareTMLoc.htm) which claims to do what you want (get type "stats" as you type) and includes "Words per minute" as said in the software description. Seems mature and with a lot of features, including skins.

Comment: Not compatible with x64 systems.